# Formulario no envia email a destinatario pasado por método $_POST

Tags: php, html5, formularios, email

Buenas comunidad, he visto que preguntas similares han sido hechas anteriormente pero no exactamente esta y estoy realmente confundido, casi seguro de que no debería tener el resultado que tengo:

Quiero hacer un formulario clásico, con tratamiento de datos en **php**, en el cual consiga que la persona que usa el mismo pueda informar tanto el email de origen como el de destino. Para ello, estoy intentando pasar el email de destino como un campo `input` del formulario por el método `$_POST[]`. Incluso con tratamiento de errores el formulario se comporta como si el email estuviera siendo enviado, pero el contenido no llega a su destino. He usado a modo de prueba un formulario con código de **bootstrap** para comprobar que no tuviera yo algún error sintáctico y lo único que he modificado es el contenido de la variable `$to`, que en vez de recibir una string fija EN el **php**, recibe por `$_POST` el contenido del `input`: Nada de nada. El mismo código solo funciona con un email fijo predefinido.

Cuando he dicho que he visto preguntas similares me refería a que las que he encontrado eran ya teniendo en cuenta que ese parámetro pasado por variable(Ya sea con contenido de **BD** o url) estaba funcionando.

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['destinationEmail'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) &&
   !filter_var($_POST['destinationEmail'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['destinationEmail'])); // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Si es que el método que estoy usando no es correcto, ¿Como configurar ese formulario para que haga exactamente eso que le pido, enviar el email a un destinatario definido en mi formulario, por el usuario?

Gracias de antemano y espero haber preguntado de la forma más correcta posible!

Comment: Gracias @Luis Daniel Rovira Contreras por la edición. Estoy usando un teclado y corrector en otro idioma.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes hacer un debug verificando que antes de la funcion mail este un valor en la variable $to si no es asi verifica el name del input y el id de acuerdo a como estés enviando desde el formulario.

Adicional recomiendo usar la funcion mail de esta manera

```
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-utf-8\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: Nombre <noreply@yourdomain.com>\r\n";
```

Agrega una copia oculta para que verifiques que si se esta enviando el correo.

```
    $headers .= "Bcc: copiatucorreo@tucorreo.com \r\n";
```

Identifica la version de php de tu servidor para que el encabezado lo tenga en cuenta.

```
    $headers .= "X-Mailer:".phpversion();
```

Finalmente haces el envió validando si se envió o no.

```
    if (mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers)) {
         echo "Se realizo el env&iacute;o del correo"; 
    } else {
         echo "Hubo un error en el env&iacute;o int&eacute;ntelo m&oacute;s tarde";
    }
```

Puedes agregar esta linea al final para ver el ultimo error que te dio esto a modo de tener un debug o algo que te ayude.

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```